# When saving in vsc, line breaks are strange

Tags: visual-studio-code

When saving in vsc, line breaks are strange.

```
    const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DiaryEditor />
      <DiaryList diaryList={dummyList} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

after

```
    const App = () => {
  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    DiaryEditor / >
    <
    DiaryList diaryList = {
      dummyList
    }
    /> <
    /div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

The above is a simple test with react code.

When I press the save button here, the line is broken and it looks strange.

Even after googling, I couldn't find a way to check the format on save in the preferences. Do you know if vsc makes the lines pretty normally when you sort or save the code?
The prettier is installed.

I'm sorry I'm not good at English

Comment: Format on save is found in preferences->settings->formatting from what I can see. If you literally mean you cannot find it in the preferences tab, you should see it in settings. Try going to the settings and searching format on save. It should come up.

Comment: Are you sure your file has `tsx` extension?

Answer (score 0):

The used formatted (you may find the list of enabled at `Ctrl+P/Format Document With...`) is considering your file to be not `typescriptreact`, but just `typescript`

Make sure your file has `tsx` extension and bottom bar shows `Typescript JSX` language selected